# timer1 instead of the external clock approch-embedded

Tags: embedded, pic

For the PIC16F877A, this PIC has no internal oscillator, but I don't want an external oscillator, so can I use TIMER1 instead of the external oscillator? Is it possible?

Comment: You mean you want to use timer 1 as the clock for the processor?!

Comment: Note that the answer to your question is in the datasheet for the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer hardware is really only capable of counting clock pulses. Therefore it needs a clock to count. On this particular chip, the clock needs to be powered by some external oscillation.

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39582b.pdf) lists four possible external clock sources that can be used in Section 14.2:

> The PIC16F87XA can be operated in four different oscillator modes. The
>   user can program two configuration bits (FOSC1 and FOSC0) to select
>   one of these four modes:
>
> • LP Low-Power Crystal
>   • XT Crystal/Resonator
>   • HS High-Speed Crystal/Resonator
>   • RC Resistor/Capacitor

If the reason you don't want to use an external oscillator is either cost or board space, a simple RC network is all you need. That should be small enough and cheap enough for almost any project.

Comment: TIMER1 in this case is a separate clock domain to the main oscillator, and does have its own oscillator.  What the chip does not have is internal timing components - you have to provide those as you say, for both the core oscillator and TIMER1 separately in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an external *oscillator* - the device has an on on-chip oscillator, however you do need an external crystal or RC network to drive the on-chip oscillator.

It is not possible to use TIMER1; it *does* have its own dedicated oscillator, but that is there to support timer operation while in *sleep* low power mode, and also requires an external crystal, so there would be no benefit over adding a crystal for the main oscillator.  There is no routing to drive the core or other peripherals from TIMER1, and even if there were, the oscillator is limited to 200KHz.